# How to make `cmd` close when using `start` inside a .bat file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am running Windows 11 and I have a `.bat` file with just this line of code:

```
start powershell -file "Z:\xxxx.ps1"
```

The problem I have is that when I execute this `.bat` file (double clicking in it) the `cmd` window opens, then the `cmd` window opens the `powershell` window and while the script `xxx.ps1` is running the `cmd` window is also kept opened... just waiting for nothing. I dont want the `cmd` window to be kept open "waiting" for the powershell script finalizes.

Is there any wait I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
start /B powershell -file "Z:\xxxx.ps1"
exit
```

This should detach the execution of the powershell and then you can continue doing whatever you want, for example exiting the script with 'exit' or 'exit /B'.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start

Comment: I tried your suggestion however using the `/B` the powershell script executed inside the CMD window instead of opening a new window (as it did before and I really prefer the powershell opening a new window). Do you have any idea how to solve this my friend?

Comment: The command `exit` as last line in a batch file is always useless and just counterproductive. The option `/B` results in running the executable (in this case *PowerShell*) as parallel executed child process of `cmd.exe` using __stdin__, __stdout__ and __stderr__ of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and resulting in most cases in termination of the child process on `cmd.exe` closes itself like on execution of `exit`. This answer is of no help for the task for that reason. The real solution is not using a batch file at all just to run *PowerShell* for execution of a *PowerShell* script.